# Pulsar-manager is not showing cluster details

Tags: apache-pulsar

[image]

1. In pulsar admin ui , i cannot able to see the clusters available . While creating tenant it is asking me to select cluster but nothing is avaliable in cluster list .
2. After searching in google and all i got to know by using below command we get the list of clusters and then we can update it . but when i am trying to run this command itself its throwing error [image]

While retrieving cluster details by using  this command

-> ./bin/pulsar-admin clusters list ...

I am getting the above error . please help on the same . Is there any other way to get list of clusters apart from using commands ?

Is there any specific path to run this command ? FYI , I Installed pulsar-manager using docker .

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're launching the command in `PowerShell`.
pulsar-admin is a `bash` script. Try the command `bash ./bin/pulsar-admin clusters list` (no guarantee, I don't have PS to test)